# Aurelia Testing Composed Custom Element

Tags: unit-testing, aurelia

Unit testing question:
When I test a component as per aurelia.io example,

```
...
component = StageComponent
  .withResources('components/comp/comp')
  .inView('<comp data.bind="info"></comp>')
  .boundTo({info: data});
...
```

I can query document and check attribute values of DOM nodes.

```
const nameElement = document.getElementById('elem-id');
```

When I try testing a composed element,

```
...
component = StageComponent
  .withResources('components/elemy/elemy')
  .inView('<compose view.bind="components/elemy/elemy.html" '+
        'view-model="components/elemy/elemy" model.bind="info">       </compose>')
  .boundTo({info: data});
...
```

I can see them in browser running Karma during testing and if I inspect, I see 'info' got passed in correctly to the custom element. But document queries return null:

```
const nameElement = document.getElementById('elem-id');
```

Am I missing something obvious? Reason why I want to test with compose is because that's how I use the custom element. It has no @bindable, only activate(model)

Comment: What is your exact use case / Why can't you use a custom element? Can you provide more info or the code inside the elemy view/ view-model?